# When are fiber products of Noetherian rings Noetherian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I am trying to solve the following problem as part of a question from the Fall 2021 UCLA algebra qualifying exam: is the fiber product $\mathbb{Q} \times_{\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-x)} \mathbb{Q}[x]$ in the category of commutative $\mathbb{Q}$ algebras Noetherian, where $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-x)$ is the inclusion and $\mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-x)$ is the projection?

This problem leads me to the following question: is it known when fiber products of rings are Noetherian? More specifically, is it known when fiber products of Noetherian algebras over a field are Noetherian? Specifically, I'm looking for an answer to this question which can hint towards a solution to the above problem.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be a general criterion that is helpful for solving this problem.  The way I would solve it would be to explicitly figure out what the fiber product looks like and directly show it is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

Comment: There are actually some results. [00IT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IT) looks like it might be applicable, and you can probably get some other results by googling "Fiber products of noetherian rings" (I think I recall that there was a Japanese mathematician by the name of Ogoma who published a few papers on this in the 80s). I do agree with Eric Wofsey that you might be better off just doing the computation for this problem though.

Answer (score 1):

The fiber product is $\{(a, b) : b - a \in (x^2 - x)\}$. First note that $b$ completely determines $a$ since $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2-x)$ is injective. Write $b$ as $p (x^2-x) = q$, with $\deg(q) = 1$. Then, we must have $q = a$. Furthermore, note that $q$ cannot have degree 1.

Therefore, we are looking at $\{b \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : b \bmod x^2-x \text{ has degree 0}\}$. Warning: a subring of a Noetherian ring might not be Noetherian, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220679/can-someone-explain-this-non-noetherian-subring-example).